# Unable to compile LLVM 5.0.0 with MSVC 14.0

Tags: c++11

I am trying to compile LLVM 5.0.0 from source on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 14.0 (2015).

I used the following cmake flags:

```
CMAKEOPTIONS += -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=$(PYTHON_PATH)/bin/python
CMAKEOPTIONS += -D LLVM_ENABLE_TERMINFO=0
CMAKEOPTIONS += -D LLVM_ENABLE_EH=1
CMAKEOPTIONS += -D LLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=1
CMAKEOPTIONS += -D LLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS:BOOL=ON -D LLVM_ABI_BREAKING_CHECKS:STRING="FORCE_OFF"
```

The compilation fails with:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   C2039
>   'iterator_facade_base,0,1>
>
> > ,std::forward_iterator_tag,llvm::PHINode const ,__int64,llvm::PHINode const *,llvm::PHINode const &>': is not a member of
> >     'llvm::BasicBlock::phi_iterator_impl' (compiling source
> >     file
> >     S:\authama\3p-tmw\3p\derived\win64\LLVM5\llvm-debug\lib\Target\AMDGPU\Utils\AMDGPUBaseInfo.cpp)
> >     LLVMAMDGPUUtils
> >     s:\authama\3p-tmw\3p\derived\win64\llvm5\llvm-debug\include\llvm\ir\basicblock.h
> >     294

Which points to:

```
290     bool operator==(const phi_iterator_impl &Arg) const { return PN == Arg.PN; }
291 
292     PHINodeT &operator*() const { return *PN; }
293 
294     using phi_iterator_impl::iterator_facade_base::operator++;
295     phi_iterator_impl &operator++() {
296       assert(PN && "Cannot increment the end iterator!");
297       PN = dyn_cast<PHINodeT>(std::next(BBIteratorT(PN)));
298       return *this;
299     }
```

The source compiles with GCC 4.9/Debian8, so I am guessing I missed something to do with setting up the compiler correctly. 
Any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: Or alternatively bootstrap llvm with a pre-build llvm installer?

Comment: LLVM 5 is available as installer for Windows, so you could use it out of the box, if you have no special reason to compile it from source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will attempt MSVC 2017 (and post back). Might have to fall back to the installer is that fails.

Comment: @jvstech - thanks! 2017 worked. I can accept that as an answer if you post it (or will wait for a bit and do that myself).

Comment: @AshishUthama Not a problem; I moved my comment to an answer since it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was once told by one of the VCPP developers, "please upgrade to 2017; 2015 is an ancient bug farm." Less than useful in many instances, but if you're using the community version of 2015 (or are in a position to upgrade pro/enterprise 2015 to 2017), try upgrading to 2017 and see if that fixes it.

I had a similar problem with 2015 that turned out to be an actual compiler bug and that appears to be the issue here as well.